# Xcode - Swift - NSURL : "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: php, xcode, swift, nsurl, null

I'm trying to test an OAuth2 implementation in a Xcode Playground, using a PHP API and a Swift client. Basically, my code looks like this

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:9142/account/validate")!
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody!.setValue("password", forKey: "grant_type")
// Other values set to the HTTPBody

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response, data, error) in
    // Handle response here
}
```

But I keep getting this error when I instantiate the url variable :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I tried not unwrapping it when I instantiate it but rather when I use it, it didn't change anything, the error appears on the first time I unwrap it.

It keeps getting even weirder.. The following

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:9142/account/validate")!
println(url)
```

outputs

> http://localhost:9142/account/validate
>       fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I really don't understand where the error can come from, as I'm really new to Swift

Comment: The error can easily come from request.HTTPBody! since you forced unwrapped  HTTPBody. Follow this tutorial http://jamesonquave.com/blog/making-a-post-request-in-swift/ to make a post request

Comment: Your error isn't coming from url definition. Check the request to see HTTPBody does exist

Comment: Wow, I commented the lines I used the HTTPBody!, and it actually came from there ! I found it was from the NSURL since Xcode put the error on this line. Thanks a lot for helping me !

Comment: Please note that you will get a similar error with url definition if there is a space in the string you are using, e.g. `url = NSURL(string="http://test.com/something?argument=variable containing space") `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is you are forced unwrapping the HTTPBody which is set to nil, causing a runtime error at this line:

```
request.HTTPBody!.setValue("password", forKey: "grant_type")
```

You need to create an NSData object for your request body and then assign it to the request.HTTPBody as per the following code:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:9142/account/validate")!
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

// Create a parameter dictionary and assign to HTTPBody as NSData
let params = ["grant_type": "password"]
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: nil)

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response, data, error) in
    // Handle response here
}
```

I hope this helps solves your problem.

## Update:

In order to serialise data without using a JSON serializer, you can create your own similar to below:

```
func dataWithParameterDictionary(dict: Dictionary<String, String>) -> NSData? {
    var paramString = String()

    for (key, value) in dict {
        paramString += "\(key)=\(value)";
    }

    return paramString.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
}
```

and call it like such:

```
let dict = ["grant_type": "password"]
let data = dataWithParameterDictionary(dict)
request.HTTPBody = data
```

Comment: I tried to pass a Dictionary using dataWithJSONObject, but it doesn't seem to be parsed correctly, however it works well when I use String.dataUsingEncoding().. I would like to be able to provide a dictionary and not worry about writing a correct query string.

Basically, when I use
`NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: nil)`,
`json_encode($request->request->all())` in my API results as
`{"{\"password\":\"aaaaa\",\"grant_type\":\"password\",\"client_id\":\"testSwift\",\"username\":\"bbbbb\"}":""}`

Comment: I'll update my answer with a non-json request serializer as well shortly.

Comment: Also, to get the objects form the JSON in your API, I believe you should be using `json_decode()` rather than `json_encode()`.